# HDF5 Library, compile problems

Tags: c++, c, linker, hdf5, unresolved-external

I am using the library of the hdf5group to access and parse such H5 Files. Actually I am trying to compile this example: https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5G/h5ex_g_traverse.c using Visual Studio 2015 64 bit mode.

I get seven errors equal to

```
unresolved external symbol __imp_H5Fopen
```

Some library functions seem to work fine but some can not be found. I actually copied all headers an libs to be certain. I also realize the an unresolved external usually indicated a missing or wrong dll but these are all lib files. There is not a single dll in play.

I would be very grateful for any help on this matter. It already kept me stuck all-day long. :/ The /D option of the comiler is set.

Best
Patrick

Comment: Are you sure you have included all the header files, and that the compiler knows about all the lib and dll files?

Comment: *I also realize the an unresolved external usually indicated a missing or wrong dll* -- No it doesn't.  It means that a library or object module is missing from your build that provides this function.  A DLL has no role in the building of an application -- none of those DLL's even need to exist to build the application successfully.  The only time a DLL comes into play is when your application is finally running.

Comment: elyashiv, definitely all header files are includes. the compiler knows about the lists. I just checked again if they are all in there.

Comment: You probably need the `.lib` files.  If there are associated DLLs, then these are like "stubs" which tell the linker which DLLs symbols reside in.  The DLLs are then (usually) located at run time.

Comment: I added all available lib files and there are no dll files at all. I am not having any better ideas either. This is frustrating.